# What are the CSS differences between IE and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wanted: Resource for documented Cross-Browser differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886947/wanted-resource-for-documented-cross-browser-differences)

i was hoping if there's a question in SO that covers the whole issue but i couldn't find one, i need to understand all the CSS differences between IE,and Firefox for example: **display**,**positioning**, that's all what i know, since i am not very experienced with CSS
there are lots of other differences i was hoping if someone expert can clarify them out, thanks in advance, and let's concentrate more on IE 9, and Firefox 8, not the old versions.

Comment: A full overview of differences will not fit in the format of a Stack Overflow question. Related: [Dealing with Firefox and Internet Explorer's Differences](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1045830)

Comment: Have a look at this [CSS Differences Between IE and Firefox: display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400055/css-differences-between-ie-and-firefox-display)

Comment: Please be careful to ask question like this. This answer can be wrote to a wiki page: You can see one here at:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css

Comment: that table isn't really up-to-date, [Quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/) will give you much better information...

Comment: While this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.